# Как в Fragment получить Bundle от Activity

Tags: android, android-bundle, fragment-manager

У меня используется  NavigateDrawer Activity и мне нужно передать данные с Activity  в Fragment. При попытке получить данные в Фрагменте в методе  getArguments().getString("data");  - получаю  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Activity.class

```
public class  MainActivity extends Activity implements onEventListener,...{

  private static FragmentManager fragmentManagerPass;

  private DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout;
  private ListView myDrawerList;
  private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle myDrawerToggle;




@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_nav_draw);
        /* ... */
    }

    /* 
        ...

    */

  @Override
    public void mySomeEvent(String inputPair) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity receive(adopt) " + input_mySome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        fragmentManagerPass = getFragmentManager();

        MyFragment argumentFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("data", "This is Argument Fragment fromActivity");
        argumentFragment.setArguments(data);

    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(
                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id
        ) {

            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MainList(); 
                break;
            case 1:
                 fragment = new ScreenTwo();      
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();            
            myDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            myDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(viewsNames[position]);
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(myDrawerList);

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Fragment.class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    Button buttonOne,buttonTwo ;
    TextView txtOne,txtTwo,txtThree,txtFour;

    int myInt;
    String myStr;

    //  private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


 public interface onEventListener {
        public void mySomeEvent(String s);
    }

    onEventListener myEventListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_converter,container,false);

        txtOne = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        Button buttonOne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do something
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtFour.setText("hello1");

            }
        });
        //receive data from activity

        //Get Argument that passed from activity in "data" key value
        String getArgument = getArguments().getString("data");//java.lang.NullPointerException
        txtOne.setText(getArgument);//set string over textview

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Bundle Fragmnet is "+getArgument);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment2 onCreateView");

        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: У вас что-то совсем непонятно по коду чего вы выделаете и чего от своих действий ждёте. Вы вашему одному фрагменту задаёте аргументы, но фрагмент этот не отображаете. А другие, без аргументов, не отображаете. Плюс код плохо отформатирован. Мы этак не сможем вам помочь

Comment: кода просто там много вырезал лишнее оставил как мне кажется самое основное

Answer (score 1):

**Обновление класса MyFragment**

Для того, чтобы передать данные в Fragment, надо в MyFragment.class добавить:

```
private static String EXTRA_STRING = "my_fragment_extra_string";
```

Затем, добавить статический метод

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String message) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(EXTRA_STRING, message);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Чтобы получить данные в фрагменте, в метод onCreateView добавить следующий код:

```
String myMessage = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_AMOUNT);
```

**Создание объектов фрагмента**

Теперь создание фрагментов будет происходить **не через конструктор фрагмента**, а через **метод newInstance**, в который можно будет передать String (или что-то другое, все зависит от сигнатуры метода newInstance).

Comment: получаю тот же вылет приложения,в View onCreateView  на строке String myMessage = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_STRING);   --- java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference   - мне кажется это как-то связано  NavigationDrawer когда происходит загрузка этого фрагмента потомучто даже проверка на null  не спасает от вылета

Comment: Вы экземпляр вашего фрагмента как создаете? Покажите эту строчку.

Comment: fragmentManagerPass = getFragmentManager();

        MyFragment argumentFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("data", "This is Argument Fragment fromActivity");
        argumentFragment.setArguments(data);

Comment: Зачем вы спрашиваете совет, а потом поступает по-своему? Я же написал, что создание фрагмент надо делать не через их конструктор, а через статический метод newInstance